# 401 Unauthorized: @angular/cli@latest - Angular 7.0.4

Tags: angular, npm

When starting my project today, I found the following error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'whitelist' of undefined
    at isFiltered (:1:5016)
    at Object.x [as send] (:1:74196)
    at DevtoolsExtension.push../node_modules/@ngrx/store-devtools/fesm5/store-devtools.js.DevtoolsExtension.notify (store-devtools.js:210)

So after searching, I decided to reinstall @angular/cli, but impossible.

I saw there was some security issues on npm today, so I wiped out everything and downloaded a brand new version of nvm.

However, it still can't install angular/cli because of a 401!

Now using node v11.3.0 (npm v6.4.1)
➜  ~ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized: @angular/cli@latest

Is it maybe related to https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/issues/116 ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an error at npm, we are getting the same error since this morning, both local machines an deployment servers. To fix this problem, just remove you local ".npmrc" file. This can be either in your user directory (c:/Users/You) or in the project directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
I finally managed it by using npm login
I believe both ways works

Answer (score 0):

Please check your _auth Key in .npmrc file. May be it is expired or you have put wrong Key there -

```
_auth = your _auth key in your organization's artifactory
email = your official email address
```